# SELECT clause with SUM condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Have this table :

```
//TEST
NUMBER             TOTAL
----------------------------
  1                158
  2                355
  3                455

//TEST1
NUMBER           QUANTITY         UNITPRICE
--------------------------------------------
   1                3                5
   1                3                6
   1                3                4
   2                4                8
   3                5                4
```

I used following query:

```
SELECT t.NUMBER,sum(t.TOTAL),NVL(SUM(t2.quantity*t2.unitprice),0)
FROM test t INNER JOIN test1 t2 ON t.NUMBER=t2.NUMBER
GROUP BY t.NUMBER;
```

OUTPUT:

```
NUMBER        SUM(TOTAL)      SUM(t2.quantity*t2.unitprice)
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1               474                       45               <--- only this wrong
  2               355                       32
```

It seem like loop for three times so 158*3 in the record.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
NUMBER        SUM(TOTAL)      SUM(t2.quantity*t2.unitprice)
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1               158                       45
 2               355                       32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand that the result of your join is something like this:

```
//TEST1
NUMBER           QUANTITY         UNITPRICE             TOTAL
--------------------------------------------------------------
   1                3                5                  158
   1                3                6                  158
   1                3                4                  158
   2                4                8                  355
   3                5                4                  455
```

It means you don't need to apply a SUM on `TOTAL`

```
SELECT t.NUMBER,t.TOTAL,NVL(SUM(t2.quantity*t2.unitprice),0)
FROM test t INNER JOIN test1 t2 ON t.NUMBER=t2.NUMBER
GROUP BY t.NUMBER, t.TOTAL;
```

Comment: You need to add `t.Total` to your `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work using a subquery separating the sums:

```
select t.num,
  sum(t.total), 
  test1sum
from test t
  join (
    select num, sum(qty*unitprice) test1sum
    from test1
    group by num
    ) t2 on t.num = t2.num
group by t.num, test1sum
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c1c7/3)

---

In regards to your sample data, you may not even need the additional `group by` on the test total field.  If that table only contains distinct ids, then this would work the same:

```
select t.num,
  t.total, 
  sum(qty*unitprice) 
from test t
  join test1 t2 on t.num = t2.num
group by t.num, t.total
```